# Data table Server side Ajax Pagination

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I Have A location Table with nearly 14 thousand records,
I need ajax pagination with server-side data. 
I used the Below Code But not working.

```
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover dataTable js-exportable" id="htmltableID">
    <thead>
    <tr>

        <th>SNO</th>
        <th>Location</th>
        <th>City</th>
        <th>State</th>


    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    <?php
    $i = 1;
    foreach ($data as $row) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $i . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row->location . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row->city . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row->state . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        $i++;
    }
    ?>
    </tbody>
</table>

<script>
    var oTable = "";
    $(document).ready(function () {
        oTable = $('#htmltableID').dataTable({
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "bServerSide": true,
            "sAjaxSource": "location",
            "sServerMethod": "POST",
            "iDisplayLength": 5
        });
    });
</script>
```

By Using this Code I am getting error Msg "DataTables warning: table id=htmltableID - Cannot reinitialise DataTable. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/3" and "DataTables warning: table id=htmltableID - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1"

Comment: `http://datatables.net/tn/1` It may be the issue with data which is returning from the ajax source url you provided `location` was not properly json encoded, Please check the response in browser console whether response is proper json or not

Comment: I think above code is running in same url `location` right??

Comment: I have updated with json return data "location/loadRecord". now i dont know how to return the data with in the tbody tag. How to do this in above jquery

Comment: @VaraPrasad yes ,code is running in same url location

Answer (score 0):

You should have below type of code in main file. Let's say `Maindata.php`

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover dataTable js-exportable" id="htmltableID">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>SNO</th>
            <th>Location</th>
            <th>City</th>
            <th>State</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>

<script>
    var oTable = "";
    $(document).ready(function () {
        oTable = $('#htmltableID').dataTable({
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "bServerSide": true,
            "sAjaxSource": "location",
            "sServerMethod": "POST",
            "iDisplayLength": 5
        });
    });
</script>
```

And the data(json) needs to be fetch from other file, let's say `loadrecords.php`(In your case it was `location/loadRecord`)

```
<?php
// $data is the list of records fetched from database

// No need to print the data since we need to provide json data to dataTable, so Below code not required
/*
$i = 1;
foreach ($data as $row) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $i . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row->location . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row->city . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row->state . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    $i++;
}
*/

// Data which you needs to send in 'location/loadRecord' should be like this (In my case it was `loadrecords.php`)
/*{
    "data": [
        ["1","Location 1","City 1","State 1"],
        ["2","Location 2","City 2","State 2"],
        .....
        .....
        ["N","Location N","City N","State N"]
    ]
}*/

// Loop the data records fetched from database and prepare array in below format
$json_arr = array(
    "data" => array(
        array("1","Location 1","City 1","State 1"),
        array("2","Location 2","City 2","State 2"),
        ...............
        ...............
        array("N","Location N","City N","State N"),
    )
);
echo json_encode($json_arr);
```

data will have N no.of rows with 4 columns since you want to display 4 columns in the table so related data needs to be provided in json